# c#, Add hyperlink to text entity for autocad file

Tags: c#, autocad

I'm trying to write a DXF file with 10,000 text entities. Each text entity needs to be hyperlinked to the corresponding image. How can I do it using c#. Here is a small demo of my code.

e,g.,
how to add Hyperlink to text
            **@"H:\VS_Programm\Image_hyperlink\google.jpg";**

I am using  [Netdxf](https://www.nuget.org/packages/netDXF/2.2.0.1) library.

```
using netDxf;


namespace Image_Hyperlink
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        DxfDocument dxf = new DxfDocument();
        string file = @"H:\VS_Programm\Image_hyperlink\hyperlink.dxf";


        private void B_OK_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            Text sText = new Text("google", new Vector2(10,10), .05);
            sText.Layer = new Layer("TScan_Z");
            sText.Layer.Color.Index = 4;

            // ADD  Hyperlink to text
            **@"H:\VS_Programm\Image_hyperlink\google.jpg";**


            dxf.AddEntity(new List<EntityObject> { sText });

            dxf.Save(file);
        }
    }
}
```